# How to visually select entire broken line in NeoVim terminal

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer

(I'm using NeoVim, `vsplit term://zsh`)

If I have a long terminal line that gets broken, and go into visual mode in order to copy something, selecting the entire line does not work as I expect:

```
|$ command ./some/long|
|/path/to/file        |
```

expected:
V (visual line) selects `$ command ./some/long/path/to/file`, or even better, but probably unrealistic, without the `$`

actual:
V (visual line) selects either `$ command ./some/long` OR `/path/to/file`

Is there a way to accomplish this?